# What is "uncaught signal #9"? TextMate, Python, MacOS

Tags: python, macos, textmate

I am just learning to code in python and really enjoying going through Project Euler and trying the problems. I'm on problem #3 which asks us to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143. I have written the code below to do this and it works great for smaller values, tested up to 540995, but once I try to set it loose on 600851475143, I get an error:

> Program terminated by uncaught signal #9 after 50.95 seconds.

I am writing this on TextMate with Python 2.7.13 on a Mac running OS 10.12. Google has given me no help finding a solution to this. I would appreciate any insight.

Here is the code I'm executing:

```
n = 600851475143
fList = []
pList = []

# factor n starting with largest factor
for i in range(n-2, 2, -2):
    # if prime factor list is empty
    if len(pList) == 0:
        if n % i == 0:
            factor = i
            # as a factor is found, test for primality
            for k in range(factor-2, 2, -2):
                if factor % k == 0:
                    if factor not in fList:
                        fList.append(factor)
            if factor not in fList:
               pList.append(factor)
print(pList)
```

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Not sure what signal 9 on Osx means (Under *nix it is a SIGKILL). But your code will run for a VERY, VERY long time. Your for loop will execute about 300 billion loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of memory. So your solution works up to 540995 which is relatively small number compare to 600851475143. Remember you are doing a nested loop so your algorithm's runtime is `O(n)^2`. In another word your loops are running for a very big number of times. you can find more about algorithmic complexity [here](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/). That being said here how I would approach the problem

```
n = 600851475143
i = 2
while i * i < n:
    while n % i == 0:
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1
print n
```

hope that helps and good luck :)